# React Router Without Changing URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to have routing that works **without changing the URL**.

Before implementing this on my own, I tried to look for something by react router. I saw that there is such a thing called **`createMemoryHistory`**:

> createMemoryHistory([options])
>
> createMemoryHistory creates an in-memory history object that does not
>   interact with the browser URL. This is useful for when you need to
>   customize the history object used for server-side rendering, for
>   automated testing, or for when you do not want to manipulate the
>   browser URL, such as when your application is embedded in an iframe.

But beyond this paragraph there aren't any usage examples and I can't find a usage for this anywhere, i.e: how to use `Link` component to navigate without a pathname, by which parameter do I route if not pathname, etc.

Is this right for my needs, or do I have to implement a router on my own?

Comment: see my blog post as example how to use MemoryRouter https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-use-react-routing-into-webview-for-vscode-extensions/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MemoryHistory is a "history provider", which you can supply to React Router like this:

```
const memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory(options);

// In your Router configuration
<Router history={memoryHistory} routes={routes} />
```

Beyond the initial configuration, everything else should work exactly the same as with regular browser history.

This article describes how to use different providers with React Router: [Histories](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md)

Comment: Thanks. It's unclear (from the article as well) what resides in `routes` and how to declare them. The usual implementation for example is: `<Route pathname="home" component={ Home } />` and you navigate using `<Link to="/home">Home</Link >`. But now there shouldn't be a pathname. I tried to simply switch histories and keep the others intact and it failed.

Comment: Actually, I'm testing this again on a different project and it seems to work. I'll keep testing.

Comment: ``routes={routes}`` is just an alternate way of defining routes. You can use ``<Route>`` component as well, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Turns out the original project I tried this on had some issues, this works in a new project. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

React Router 4+ has a MemoryRouter

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'

<MemoryRouter>
  <App/>
</MemoryRouter>
```

> A `<Router>` that keeps the history of your “URL” in memory (does not
> read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser
> environments like React Native.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter

Comment: note: if you use MemoryRouter you do not get back button capabilties

Comment: did not work until I used `import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom"`