# How to redirect in React Router without changing the url

Tags: redirect, react-router

How can I implement `maybeGoToBar` such that - depending on the name - I show the `Foo` component or the `Bar` component **without changing the url**?

```
function maybeGoToBar(nextState, replace, callback) {
  const name = nextState.params.name;
  if (name === "Bob") {
    // do something to route to /bar
    // but keep showing /bob/foo as the current location
    // in the browser address bar
  }
  callback();
}

<Route path=":name/foo" onEnter={maybeGoToBar} component={Foo} >
<Route path="bar" component={Bar} >
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you shouldn't be using router to do this. You should store a state variable in your component (the initial value of it could be taken from the url if desired) and you should choose what child to show based on the state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Without Changing URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721812/react-router-without-changing-url)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a memory history.

[Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#creatememoryhistoryoptions)

Comment: I read that this option has the downside that the initial url (used to open the page) is not processed by the router.