# How to implement React App navigation for VSCode extension with webview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-router-dom, vscode-extensions

I've faced with the issue while developing `VSCode Extension` using `React`. I know that `VSCode` allows integrating for `HTML/JS/CSS` code using `Webview`. But links do not work into it, so `react-router` for Web doesn't work.

**Doesn't work:**

```js
<Link to="/my/url">
```

My question is how to implement navigation into vscode extension webview using React navigation?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `react-router` purely for linking your components together without any URL support (i.e. in this extension of yours), you can use `createMemoryHistory`. See [React Router Without Changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721812/react-router-without-changing-url). Also consider [`MemoryRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) for `react-router` v4.

Example:

```js
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {/* All your routes, i.e. stuff you usually put in <Router>.
          Link elements now work because the "URL" is stored in memory. */}
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `react-router` rather than `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Maybe, but it's just re-exported anyway, so IMO `react-router-dom` is better for consistency with the majority of online resources. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router-dom/modules/index.js#L2