# React Router: Navigate without changing the URL sometimes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In React Router V4, I have a NotFoundScreen component set up to current standards.

It will catch all completely unknown routes fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to navigate to it without changing the browsers URL. The rest of the app uses typical history.push() URL changing behavior, so I'm not sure I can use the memoryHistory described **here:** [React Router Without Changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721812/react-router-without-changing-url)

To highlight my problem, if a user does not exist, it would be convenient programmatically navigate to **NotFoundScreen** without changing the users incorrect URL so they could catch a typo or use the browser's back button.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import UserScreen from './UserScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import NotFoundScreen from './NotFoundScreen';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/user/:userID' component={UserScreen}/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomeScreen}/>
        
        {/*NotFoundScreen will pick up all unknown routes. I want 
        to navigate here without changing the URL*/}
        <Route component={NotFoundScreen}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: That's not a job for the router. You can conditionally **render** the `NotFoundScreen` instead of your normal content, but the router renders content **in response to** a change in the url.

Comment: That seems like a good solution to me, thanks for the help.